# Error installing laravel 5 by composer

Tags: php, git, symfony, composer-php, laravel-5.1

I'm using windows 7 and trying to install laravel by composer.I've installed composer in my system and added git to my path earlier.I also downloaded a fresh copy of laravel and paste it into my server.Now,when i run this comment to install laravel ,i get this error.

> C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-master>composer install
>
> Loading composer repositories with package information
>
> Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
>
> - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v2.7.5)
>
>   Downloading: 100%
>
>   Downloading: 100%
>
>   Downloading: 100%
>
>   Failed to download symfony/var-dumper from dist: The  http//api.github.com/repos/sym
>     fony/var-dumper/zipball/ba8c9a0edf18f70a7efcb8d3eb35323a10263338 file could not be downlo
>     aded: failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did n
>     ot properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because conne
>     cted host has failed to respond.
>
>   Now trying to download from source
>
>   - Installing symfony/var-dumper (v2.7.5)
>       Cloning ba8c9a0edf18f70a7efcb8d3eb35323a10263338
>
> [RuntimeException]
>     Failed to clone git@github.com:symfony/var-dumper.git via git, https, ssh protocols,
>     aborting.
>
> - git://github.com/symfony/var-dumper.git
>     Cloning into 'C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-master\vendor\symfony\var-dumper'...
>     fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
>     github.com[0: 192.30.252.128]: errno=No error
> - https://github.com/symfony/var-dumper.git
>     Cloning into 'C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-master\vendor\symfony\var-dumper'...
>     fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/symfony/var-dumper.git/': Failed connec
>     t to github.com:443; No error
>
>   - git@github.com:symfony/var-dumper.git
>       Cloning into 'C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel-master\vendor\symfony\var-dumper'...
>       Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.252.131' (RSA) to the list of known h
>       osts.
>       Permission denied (publickey).
>       fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>
>   and the repository exists.

Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

and here is my composer.json file :

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.1.*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "pre-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan clear-compiled"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
```

}

Comment: It looks like internet connection issue. If you retry now, is it still broken?

Comment: Also, could you provide your `composer.json`?

Comment: Sadly this is common when installing things from Composer. It has nothing to do with Laravel or Symfony or PHP. The only solution is to wait a bit and execute the same command again.

Comment: @TomášVotruba added in my post.Please try to help me.

Comment: @JavierEguiluz I've tried again and again a lots of time but failed every time :(

Answer (score -1):

Sadly, this connection error is common when installing projects via GitHub + Composer. If the problem persists after several retries, I'd recommend you to install Laravel using their installer instead. See http://laravel.com/docs/5.1#installation

The installer just downloads a single ZIP file instead of trying to download lots of small files from GitHub. This makes it much faster and reliable. Symfony project uses this very same trick and recommends only to use the Symfony Installer.